# Getting error while sending mail in java

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail

I was trying to send mail using java. The code i was using worked when I used it with GMail's SMTP server ("smtp.gmail.com"). But when I changed the code (smtp_host_name, smtp_port properties and authentication UserID/Pwd) to send email through the SMTP server of my ISP provider, this code failed.

Here is my code-

```
String host = "smtp server host of my isp provider";

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol.", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true"); 

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(messageText, "text/html");

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(host, user, pass);
```

And i am getting this error-

```
 javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response; 
 nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

The problem is i am able to send mails from the same code from my system workspace. But after i upload the war file to host, i get the above error. I think i disabled SSL but still getting this error. Can someone please help. Its urgent...

I followed the steps given below but still i am getting the same error.
Here is my code now-

```
 String host = "mail.myweb.com", user = emailUser, pass = emailPasswd;

    String to = emailID;
    String from = emailFrom;
    String subject = subj;
    String messageText = message;
    boolean sessionDebug = true;

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(messageText, "text/html");

    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(host, user, pass);

    try {
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error" + e.getMessage());
    }
    transport.close();
}
```

Here is the full stacktrace

```
 javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1611)
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1369)
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
common.sendMail.(sendMail.java:35)
frontend.reply.sendfeedback(reply.java:74)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: You're trying to use SSL on a non-SSL connection, exactly as the error says. Your last Property explicitly does that.

Comment: I removed the last property but still its not working....

Comment: @BhaskarSharma, Did you find any solution for this? I am also facing same.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
```

is enabling SSL on this connection; make it false instead , or just take it out.

Also the dot at the end of this property name is suspicious, although probably innocuous:

```
props.put("mail.transport.protocol.", "smtp");
```

Comment: Hi, i tried that but still it is not working. I can't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Hi try to add following properties for non ssl smtp connection

```
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

for example the **ssl** connection properties are

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.username", "email@gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", "password");
    props.put("mail.smtp.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

**Non ssl** properties are

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", "email@mydomain.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", "password");
    props.put("mail.smtp.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mydomain.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a `Transport` object with `smtps` protocol. Use [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) version 1.4.1 or later.
I am not sure if this was supported in earlier versions.
Each of `smtp.jar` and `imap.jar` contains a resource file named `javamail.providers` with following entries:

```
# JavaMail SMTP provider Sun Microsystems, Inc
protocol=smtp; type=transport; class=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport; vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc;
protocol=smtps; type=transport; class=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport; vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc;  

# JavaMail IMAP provider Sun Microsystems, Inc
protocol=imap; type=store; class=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore; vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc;
protocol=imaps; type=store; class=com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore; vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc;
```

These resources are loaded when you create a mail session object. `DEBUG` trace is as follows:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/E:/Ravi/work/eclipse-workspace/temp/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/E:/Ravi/work/eclipse-workspace/temp/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/smtp.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsy stems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsy stems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
```

We need to get an instance of `com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport` to use `smtps` protocol.

```
Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtps");
```

As the resource has a provider defined for this protocol, `Transport` object is generated without any exception.

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
```

If all your inputs are correct you would get a success. `DEBUG` on a sample execution is shown below:

```
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 mx.google.com ESMTP d2sm12188996pbw.39
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465

EHLO sreekarreddy
250-mx.google.com at your service, [117.195.223.189]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH
250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<rrarepally@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK d2sm12188996pbw.39
RCPT TO:<rrarepally@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK d2sm12188996pbw.39
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   rrarepally@gmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead d2sm12188996pbw.39
From: rrarepally@gmail.com
To: rrarepally@gmail.com
Message-ID: <19230370.0.1335124760953.JavaMail.Administrator@sreekarreddy>
Subject: test email over smtps
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

hello world
.
250 2.0.0 OK 1335124739 d2sm12188996pbw.39
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection d2sm12188996pbw.39
```